# python pptx align image to center of slide

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-pptx

I need to add an image to a pptx slide, and want to locate it in the center of the slide, without having to calculate the size and alignment manually,

I found a question about doing so with text: 
[question about center aligning text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935137/center-align-text-with-python-pptx)

And the documentation about doing so with text:
[documentation about center aligning text](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/PpParagraphAlignment.html)

But can't find a way to do it for an image,

Ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not going to work the same way as text; there's no center justification or alignment property on an image. You'll need to use a formula.

```
image.left = (prs.slide_width - image.width) / 2
```

Comment: i tried using the slide width, and this is the error i am getting AttributeError: 'Slide' object has no attribute 'slide_width'

Comment: @captainshai The slide width is a property of the presentation (same for all slides), not for an individual slide. So you need to use the `Presentation.slide_width` property. `prs` above is the "standard-ish" variable name for a `Presentation` object, used throughout the documentation.

Comment: For me, this gave an error: `TypeError: value must be an integral type, got <class 'float'>`. But that was easy to fix with `image.left = int((prs.slide_width - image.width) / 2)` and the result is perfect. Thanks for the original answer (and question)!

Answer (score 3):

**Answer 08/13/2020**

This is what worked for me:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from PIL import Image


# instantiate presentation
prs = Presentation()

# change slide sizes to Widescreen
slide_size = (16, 9)
prs.slide_width, prs.slide_height = Inches(slide_size[0]), Inches(slide_size[1])

# convert pixels to inches
def px_to_inches(path):
    
    im = Image.open(path)
    width = im.width / im.info['dpi'][0]
    height = im.height / im.info['dpi'][1]
    
    return (width, height)

img = px_to_inches('logo.png')

# insert logo image
left = Inches(slide_size[0] - img[0]) / 2
top = Inches(slide_size[1] - img[1]) / 2
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture('logo.png', left, top)
```

Comment: Getting a `KeyError: 'dpi'` from within the `px_to_inches()` function with this solution. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here's the PasteBin: https://pastebin.com/71y0qD8Z