# pptx-python align table to centre of slide

Tags: python, python-pptx

I want to create a table of a specific row and column number and size and align it to the centre of the slide.

Is there any way to do this?

I found a way to align image: [python pptx align image to center of slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149992/python-pptx-align-image-to-center-of-slide)

but cannot find anything about aligning tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just centre in the same way you would any other shape.

Once created.

```
shape.left = int((presentation.slide_width / 2) - (shape.width / 2))
shape.top = int((presentation.slide_height / 2) - (shape.height / 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Presentation` object has `slide_width` and `slide_height`. The `Shapes` object has (settable) `left`, `width`,`top`,`height`.

Between these you should be able to position (and size) a shape anywhere you like on the slide. Centring is a matter of geometry.